# How to build ubuntuone-client so that it doesn't depend on nautilus and gnome

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, build, source

Basically I want to build ubuntuone-client so that it doesn't have nautilus and gnome related dependencies. Can this be done? if so how?

Comment: pardon me, but what do you expect to accomplish with just `u1sdtool`?

Comment: I was thinking if I could avoid some nautilus and gnome related dependencies if I wanted to build ubuntuone on other distro

Comment: edited your question to reflect what you actually want

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu One file synchronization daemon, `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` and the related commandline utility `u1sdtool`, are python programs and as such don't need “building” in the traditional sense (the parts of `ubuntuone-client` that need building are the nautilus extension—which you don't want—and the icons used by it). At runtime `u1sdtool` simply talks to `syncdaemon` over dbus, and `syncdaemon` has very narrow dependencies on some services provided by the Ubuntu desktop, and then again only via dbus (so you could in theory satisfy the dependencies with another service that provided the same API).

You need something on the session bus providing `org.freedesktop.Secret.Session` and related interfaces. This is used by `ubuntu-sso-client`, which is used by `syncdaemon` to provide the needed credentials.

You probably also want something on the system bus providing `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` (typically Network Manager itself) to give the `syncdaemon` awareness of whether you are connected to the network or not. This isn't essential, however.

You also need the following python libraries: `configglue`, `dbus` (obviously), `oauth`, `pyinotify`, `simplejson`, `twisted`, `xdg`, and `ubuntuone.storageprotocol` (which in turn depends on some of the above and also `protobuf`). Optionally you could have `pynotify`, `zeitgeist`, and some Unity-related things that I'm assuming you won't have.

Good luck porting, and if I've forgotten anything or you get stuck, please let us know!

Comment: Basically `org.freedesktop.secrets` is handled by gnome-keyring from what I understood. Well I kinda got everything working without any error message but now I am stuck on ubuntu-sso. The gui does nothing when I enter my email and password from ubuntuone control panel?

Comment: ubuntu-sso-client-gtk talks to ubuntu-sso-client-backend over dbus, and starts it via dbus activation. You're probably missing the dbus services files.

Comment: Well following some log file it seems that sso credentials are not set. Is there anyway to pass email and password through commandline

Comment: Basically I am getting SSLHandShake error on sso log, anyway to avoid this ??