# SSLHandShake Error while porting ubuntuone-client without gnome and nautilus dependencies

Tags: ubuntu-one, python

Following this question

[How to build ubuntuone-client so that it doesn't depend on nautilus and gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51398/how-to-build-ubuntuone-client-so-that-it-doesnt-depend-on-nautilus-and-gnome/51724#51724)

I am stuck. The ubuntu-sso login prompt does nothing after I enter email and password. Going through log files I get SSLhandshake error. So I wanted to know if there is anything ubuntu specific on those python source that I should patch to get it working ? Or if I am doing something wrong ? I am trying to get it working on archlinux. Here are the logs on sso and ubuntuone:

```
    2011-07-20 21:50:42,543:543.970108032 - ubuntu_sso.main - ERROR - Exception while running DBus blocking code in a thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ubuntu_sso/main/linux.py", line 56, in _in_thread
    result_cb(app_name, f())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ubuntu_sso/main/__init__.py", line 103, in f
    credentials = self.processor.login(email, password, token_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ubuntu_sso/account.py", line 165, in login
    sso_service = self.sso_service_class(basic, self.service_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.12.0-py2.7.egg/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 460, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.12.0-py2.7.egg/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 299, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.12.0-py2.7.egg/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 242, in _request
    str(url), method=method, body=data, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.12.0-py2.7.egg/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 211, in _request_and_retry
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1436, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.restfulclient-0.12.0-py2.7.egg/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 130, in _request
    redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1188, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1123, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.7.1-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 911, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
2011-07-20 21:50:42,565:565.541982651 - ubuntu_sso.gui - INFO - on_login_error: args (<ubuntu_sso.gtk.gui.UbuntuSSOClientGUI object at 0x3063510>, dbus.String(u'Ubuntu One'), dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String(u'errtype'): dbus.String(u'SSLHandshakeError')}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss'))), kwargs {}.
2011-07-20 21:52:08,917:917.640924454 - ubuntu_sso.credentials - WARNING - Login/registration was denied to app dbus.String(u'Ubuntu One')
2011-07-20 21:52:08,918:918.035984039 - ubuntu_sso.main - INFO - CredentialsManagement: emitting AuthorizationDenied with app_name "Ubuntu One".
2011-07-20 21:52:08,918:918.241977692 - ubuntu_sso.gui - INFO - Calling custom close_callback <function <lambda> at 0x25b6938> with params (<gtk.Window object at 0x3046640 (GtkWindow at 0x30a4060)>, <gtk.gdk.Event at 0x2e1df08: GDK_DELETE>), {}
2011-07-20 21:52:18,923:923.69890213 - ubuntu_sso.main - INFO - Shutting down, calling <built-in function main_quit>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logs don't tell us enough about the potential dependency problems. My only suggestion (given the log) is to check the version of httplib2 and check to make sure the ssl dependencies are installed. Somehow you might have httplib2 without the extra ssl support.

I can't imagine this has much to do with nautilus and/or gnome and is more likely to do with httplib2.